# Referencing files to shrink file size

Tags: rendering, import, file-format

Okay- DAZ user here, but this question should be accessible to people who don't use it as well.

DAZ files are MUCH smaller than blender files and I realized that's because all the meshes and materials aren't actually IN the files themselves, only referenced. Is there a way to do that in Blender and is there any value in doing so?
For instance, would using said referenced models and materials effect render times in any way?

Comment: Actually, did more research and- yes there is a way to do exactly what I said and probably a decent reason for doing so as it allows you to reuse models without making large files. It's called linking in Blender: youtube.com/watch?v=qLW27XcH6lY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main goal of referencing thought the files is not in memory saving, but in saving your time in production. Let me explain.

For example, you make a movie with a character, which acts in 10 scenes. You've made 9 scenes, and in scene number 10 you've realized that something should be changed. If you just copy character from scene to scene - it would be a painful task, because you have to make this change in 10 separate files. But if your character is located in a separate file and linked into 10 scenes, it would not be a huge problem. You can just change character, and it will be updated in all 10 scenes.

To make this reference - simply pack your objects into collection, save file, and in the other file use *File* ⇾ *Link* to make a reference to the collection. Then collection is loaded, you may also click *Object* ⇾ *Relations*  ⇾ *Make library override* to get the ability to move armature bones.

Referencing may be memory-efficient, if you use the same object in the scene. Take a look at this example: The grass on the right uses a bunch of objects that's duplicated across the field, while grass on the left is simpler, but every strand is individual:

[image]

This allows to save a lot of memory and decrease the render time.

Comment: I would thank you but apparently that's not allowed for lowly newbies like me- go figure.
Thanks.
Also- I would say there would be quite an implied benefit to file size there as well if you think about it.

Comment: I do wonder and will get back on this- does this reduced file size make moving around in the end files faster or slower?

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: Thankyou again- that is SUPER useful to know. More good stuff to know- if you're NOT using this for intancing the same model over and over, "is navigation in blender faster when using linking?"- Yes and no: Yes, if you're asking about modeling, material and object modes, no if you're asking about render mode, it's actually a good deal slower. So in the end, it's not all positives as there is a small sacrifice in speed when using render mode and it's a little bit- buggy- as it shoots me out of blender for a few seconds when using render mode.